# Trouble finding source of a designer exception in VS2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

When loading the mainform of a WinForms app I'm working on, I encountered a familiar exception: a "To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved" error. The stacktrace is as follows:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    

Instances of this error (4)  

1.   Hide Call Stack 

at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.CanResetSizePropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertyAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement, CodePropertyReferenceExpression propertyReferenceEx, Boolean reportError)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
```

I know what's causing this error -- there are four lines buried somewhere in the MainForm that make reference to an image object that doesn't exist at design time. I even have an idea of how to fix the error, thanks to [this post at MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2db13f7d-9a4a-41cc-97f6-b645f33e04c7/). The trouble is, I can't find the lines from which the exception is thrown. Normally I would navigate to the exception using the [Error List window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33df3b7a.aspx), but it says that there are zero errors. Any ideas as to how I can locate the offending lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually find that this relates to a user control hosted on the form that relies on a DI container or similar, but as you say it is sometimes difficult to determine the source from the call stack the designer provides. If you're hosting a lot of controls, to figure out which controls are causing the issue without diving into each one you could:

1. Make a list of the user controls that are directly hosted on the form, then
2. Create a new temporary form, then
3. Drop each user control in your list onto the form to see which one kills the designer