# WinForm Designer Error

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm getting the following error when trying to open a WinForm (VS2010, C#):

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object
>   component, Object value)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object
>   component, Object value) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.InheritedPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object
>   component, Object value)
>
> at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertyAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeAssignStatement statement,
>   CodePropertyReferenceExpression propertyReferenceEx, Boolean
>   reportError)
>
> at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeAssignStatement statement)
>
> at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeStatement statement)

Does anyone know where to even start looking for the cause of this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble finding source of a designer exception in VS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504407/trouble-finding-source-of-a-designer-exception-in-vs2010)

Comment: VS is in no way a black box. Without code we are guessing. Start by educating yourself. Here is a good link for learning VS2010 debugging http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Comment: @lazfish It doesn't get better as a comment. IMHO you are completely missing the point.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the OP is saying based on this output how do I begin to narrow down the problem further. At first I thought this was just "hey find my error". He could still narrow down the which control has the issue with good debugging practices. If He is not familiar with debugging in VB my link could be a helpful nudge toward a strategy. But you are correct, it is in no way an answer.

Comment: @lazfish He has an error inside the _WinForms Designer_ - there is no way of debugging it (at least non I'm aware of and non that is covered in your linked article).

Comment: Thanks Uwe, your link was useful. I discovered that the way the orig authors layered the forms is.. well.. a bit of a mess. They derived one WebForm from another one and there are duplicate controls when doing it that way.

Comment: @EricR I would _never_ dare to do visual form inheritance. Never ever :-)

Comment: Tell me about it.. I've never seen anyone do that.  Now I have to scratch my head to try and fix it. :)